# Low Frequency Terms - Naive Bayes Improving Accuracy

Tags: r, naivebayes

I have thousands of factors (categorical variables) that I am applying a classification on using Naive Bayes.

My problem is that I have many factors that appear very few times in my dataset so it seems they decrease the performance of my prediction.

Indeed, I noticed that if I removed the categorical variables that were happening very few times, I had a signicant improvement of my accuracy. But ideally I would like to keep all my factors, do you know what is the best practice to do so ?

Big Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The lowest frequency terms may be adversely affecting the accuracy simply because there is not enough data to make an accurate prediction.  Hence, the observations in the training set may say nothing about the validation set.

You could combine all the lowest frequency observations into a single value.  Off-hand, I don't know what the right threshold is.  You can start by taking everything that occurs 5 or fewer times and lumping them together.

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for your reply. Thats what I did, by removing any terms appearing less than 50 times (for the highest frequency terms they appear more than 400 times). By doing that, I have an accuracy of 80%. But my problem is that I would need to include also the small terms I think. And if I do so, it drops to 20/30% of accuracy which isnt worth it...

Comment: @ML_Enthousiast . . . The threshold of 50 might be too high.  The strong drop in results suggests correlations among the rare terms.  The 80% is probably pretty good.

Comment: But in this case, what is the best practice if I want to keep all the terms, even the ones that are not appearing frequently ?